# Check if element is a member of all sets in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Here is a function that checks whether an alement `a` is a member of every set in list `l-set`.

I don't like the fact that it returns `#t` for an empty list of sets. What would be a clean fix to this problem?

```
(define memberall
  (lambda (a l-set)      
    (cond
      ((null? l-set) #t)
      ((not (member a (car l-set))) #f)
      (else (memberall a (cdr l-set))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

so this is not a question about code, but about conventions. Usually to say "a condition holds for all elements of a set" is the same as "there's no such element in the set that the condition doesn't hold for it". Which there clearly is no such element, in an *empty* set. So by convention all such "all-are-true" predicates hold for an empty set.

But if you want your function to return `#f` in such a case, just add simple entry check for this, and convert what you have right now into an inner (nested) definition:

```
(define memberall
  (lambda (a l-set) 
    (and (not (null? l-set))
      (letrec ((alltrue 
                 (lambda (l-set)
                   (cond
                     ((null? l-set) #t)
                     ((not (member a (car l-set))) #f)
                     (else (alltrue (cdr l-set)))))))
        (alltrue l-set)))))
```

Or with named `let`:

```
(define memberall
  (lambda (a l-set) 
    (and (not (null? l-set))
      (let alltrue ((l-set l-set))
        (cond
          ((null? l-set) #t)
          ((not (member a (car l-set))) #f)
          (else (alltrue (cdr l-set))))))))
```